# Convert series to pandas dataframe given the index as two columns with the same name and can t use reset_index

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a series like this:

```
transaction_date  transaction_date  ticker
2012              9                 DD        1
                  12                DD        1
2013              3                 DD        1
                  4                 CG        1
                  6                 DD        1
```

and I want to convert it to a dataframe with the column names: year, month, ticker and count. But given there are two index columns with the same name (transaction_date), everything i tried failed

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: I see, sorry. need

Comment: `df = s.rename_axis(['year','month','ticker']).reset_index(name='count')`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = s.rename_axis(['year','month','ticker']).reset_index(name='count')
```

Also in groupby code is possible use `rename`:

```
df.groupby([df['transaction_date'].dt.year.rename('year'),
            df['transaction_date'].dt.month.rename('month'),
            'ticker']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```